# select speed on indexed column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a mysql table on innodb with 4.5ish million rows.

Why is there a HUGE time difference between these (seemingly to me) almost identical select statement?

`url` is `varchar(200)`

```
select * from table where url = 12345;  take 2.715 seconds

select * from table where url = "12345"; takes 0.000 seconds
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the execution plan, but I'd guess that casting 12345 4.5 million times to varchar isn't going to be cheap.  The implicit cast occurring on the first one has overhead.  You're seeing that overhead * 4.5 million.  This isn't an "answer" because not enough information has been provided to KNOW if that's the problem.

Comment: @xQbert: Wouldn't the cast happen only once?

Comment: Perhaps if it was written `12345=url` it would happen once. but it's written `url=12345`.  I'd have to do some testing to verify though.

Comment: When you search url=12345, mysql can't use the index because '012345' , '0012345' also match. It has to convert every values to integers and do.the search.

Comment: You failed to say whether you have `INDEX(url)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the following information enlightening.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32308

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Notably, the documentation clearly states (emphasis mine):

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, **MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly**. If str_col is an indexed string column, the index cannot be used when performing the lookup in the following statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE str_col=1;
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value `1`, such as `'1'`, `' 1'`, or `'1a'`.